# In kempo karate, what's the order of the forms and combination you learn?

Tags: karate, kempo

In kempo karate, what's the order of the forms you learn ? (up to brown or black belt)

So far I know it's 1 Pinyon, 2 Pinyon, 1 Kata, Crane, 2 Kata, 3 Pinyon, 3 Kata

Also how about combinations? what's the order you learn them

Is it 7, 6, 3, 5, 2, ...

**[edit: added more forms in order]**

Comment: Welcome to Martial Arts! I'm no expert on kempo karate, but doesn't the order in which you learn differ for each dojo?

Comment: I thought about that. But I've noticed the order is usually similar in kempo Karate, and even the foot movement. Only thing that's different (As far as combination and forms) is the block or punch type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At our school, the combinations go 6 & 7, 3 & 5, 2 & 18, 4 & 8, 9 & 12, 10 & 14, 15 & 26, 11 & 17, and that is all the way through green with a brown stripe (right before brown belt).

Comment: That sounds like ours too, how about the forms? p.s. What school do you go to?

Comment: Can you add some more context to your answer? At the moment it is just a bunch of numbers, maybe you could add names/descriptions, or links?

Comment: p.s. after that it's 1 & 20 for brown strip black =]